# Multiple If statements in Microsoft Excel 2013

Tags: excel

So here is what is currently in cell A3 and A4

```
Kris Bryant (CHICAGO)    
Anthony Rizzo (CHICAGO)
```

and here is my formula to just retrieve the player's name

```
=IF(SEARCH("Kris Bryant",A3),"Kris Bryant",IF(SEARCH("Anthony Rizzo",A3),"Anthony Rizzo","")) (The next cell below is exactly the same except A4 instead of A3)
```

I would expect it to pull Kris Bryant from the first one and Anthony Rizzo from the second.  However I get the following

Kris Bryant

> `#VALUE!`

Answer (score 0):

That is because `SEARCH()` returns an error if the value is not found and a number if found.  When it moves to the second value the first part of the IF is an error and if it is an error it stops and returns the error.

Use ISNUMBER() to test for the error:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Kris Bryant",A3)),"Kris Bryant",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Anthony Rizzo",A3)),"Anthony Rizzo",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark beside the answer.  You are able to do this after the question is 15 minutes old.